# Locating keyword in .csv files

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create batch file that reads specific CSV documents from specific file, and extracts some lines that have specific number and print it out on the screen " the whole line !". The problem is I created the code but it wont work at all, whenever I tried it only prints the line numbers!?

The code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "yourDir=C:\Users\Adminm\Desktop\test11\"
set "yourExt=csv"
set "keyword=44"
set /a count=0

set linenum=!count!
set c=0


pushd %yourDir%

for %%a in (*.%yourExt%) do (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=," %%b in (%yourDir%%%a) do (
    set /a count = !count! + 1
    if NOT %%b == %keyword% (
    for /f "delims=" %%1 in ('type %yourDir%%%a') do (
    set /a c+=1 && if "!c!" equ "%linenum%" echo %%1%
    )
    )
    )
)

echo !count!

popd
endlocal
```

thanks in advance <3

Comment: Assigning string literals to variables is obfuscating

Comment: @SubjectiveKirby : I reverted your edits and re-applied them to the narrative but not the code-edits. Changing indents/layout sometimes has an effect on batch so best to retain as-posted unless it has not been posted as code with the initial 4 spaces per line.

Comment: @Magoo I didn't realise, thanks for letting me know. I'll be wary of that in the future (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%a in (*.%yourExt%) do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%a") do (
     for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%b in ("%%L") do (
     if %%b == %keyword% echo %%L
     )
    )
)
```

Assuming what you want to do is scan each file for a target string in column3, then:

Since you have already changed to `yourdir`, there's no requirement to specify it in the scan-for-filenames `for`.

Your attempt to locate the required line is clumsy. All you need to do is assign each line in turn to a *metavariable* (`%%L`) and then use `for/` to parse the *metavariable*. When the required data matches, simply `echo` the *metavariable* containing the entire line.

You've attempted to use `%%1` as a *metavariable*. `%n` for *n*=0..9 refers to the parameter number supplied to the routine. The only *officially* defined *metavariables* for use here are `%%a`..`%%z` and `%%A`..`%%Z` (one of the very few places where batch is case-sensitive) - although some other symbols also work. Numerics will not work here.